# fstream file I/O question - when to close a file stream

Tags: c++, c, fstream, crt

I am trying to work out if I need to call close on a fstream object if the intial open failed.

i.e.

```
std::fstream strm;
strm.open( "filename" );

if( ! strm.fail() )
{
    // Do something

    strm.close();  // [1]
}

strm.close();  // [2]
```

Where should *close* be called here - should it always be called [2] or only if the open succeeds[1]?

I may be going over the top here, but coming from the Windows API way of typically doing this I have *CloseHandle( ... );* embedded in my mind :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stream will be automatically closed by the fstream's destructor - there is no need to close it explicitly, unless your program logic demands it, for example if you are going to re-open it. However, closing a stream that didn't open won't cause any problems.

Answer (score 0):

No, if the stream didn't get opened there is nothing to close.